# Using razor syntax and angular

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razor

Is it possible to use AngularJS variable as Route Parameter in Razor Syntax like this?

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="job in jobs">
    <td>
        <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("editJob", new { id =  job.JobID })">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" style="color:#808080"></i>
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Right now I am using this.

```
<a href='@Url.Content("~/job/edit/"){{job.JobId}}'>
```

Comment: is it working for you?

Comment: first one is not working and the second one is working. The first one is much cleaner

Comment: then use that. If works fine. As it understood string find replace in backend works for second condition.

Comment: I was asking a question on whether its possible. Ok?

Answer (score 5):

I'd say no, since Razor is rendered server side and at that time Angular variables don't exist. Meaning `new { id = job.jobID }` will result in `{ id : null }`.

Your second solution is working because the angular string is concatenated right after the Razor part ends.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend neither solutions because mixing multiple templates is always a bit dangerous. The way our team solves this is

1. pass in all razor dependencies on in a separate script block with a dynamically created constant on in the ng-init (if only used in simple cases)
2. only use these in your angular template

A bit like this (pseudo-code, example using ng-init)

```
<div ng-app="..." ng-init="config = { rootUrl: '@Url.Content("~/job/edit/")', otherValue: ''}">

  <a href="{{config.rootUrl + job.JobId}}">...</a>
</div>
```

Comment: yes. the thing is that I want to use angular and the asp.net routing together.

Comment: @naveen this can be done fairly well like this. I'm assuming you want to use html5 pushstate for angular but map the same urls to the server with asp.net routing, correct?

So I'm understanding your core question to be "can you use the _same_ url-config to assemble the link url in razor/angular" - would that hit it?